# Having problems with Foreach object in list. Txt file output does not contain all items?

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have a class which is creating a list of objects called manufacturers. I use an XML file to create the objects which are stored in an arrayed called ManufacturerList.

Below is code from the ManufacturerImport class. This is where I create the objects.

```
 private List<Manufacturer> ManufacturerList = new List<Manufacturer>();

    public void AddManufacturer(Manufacturer manu)
    {
        ManufacturerList.Add(manu);
    }

    public List<Manufacturer> GetManufacturers()
    {
        return ManufacturerList;
    }
```

As you can see, I need to pass this list to other parts of my code so I have a GetManufacturers function.

In my Main function I am using the following code:

```
 List<Manufacturer> mList = ManuImport.GetManufacturers();

         TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\manu.txt");

        foreach (Manufacturer manu in mList)
        {

           //Output name to txt file. 
            tw.WriteLine(manu.ManufacturerName);

            Console.WriteLine(manu.ManufacturerName);
            Console.WriteLine(manu.ShortManufacturerName);
            Console.WriteLine(manu.ManufacturerDirectory);
            Console.WriteLine(manu.ManuId);
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
        }



  //Forgot to include this in example. Has been in code from beginning. sorry for confusion
            tw.Close();
```

I have debugged the code and found that the list is successfully being copied over to mList. I am a little confused as to how the mList list can contain all the objects I require but when I step through the list, I dont get the correct output.

My list has 486 objects but the output only writes 333 of those to the txt file. What is also odd is that the console outputs different manufacturers to the list.

Any thoughts would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Is it possible that you don't close the output file, causing the last 153 items to get left in the buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enclose your `TextWriter` object in a `using` block.

```
List<Manufacturer> mList = ManuImport.GetManufacturers();

using(TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\manu.txt"))
{
    foreach (Manufacturer manu in mList)
    {

       //Output name to txt file. 
        tw.WriteLine(manu.ManufacturerName);

        Console.WriteLine(manu.ManufacturerName);
        Console.WriteLine(manu.ShortManufacturerName);
        Console.WriteLine(manu.ManufacturerDirectory);
        Console.WriteLine(manu.ManuId);
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
    }
}
```

There are two reasons for this:

First, fundamentally, `TextWriter` implements `IDisposable`, which means that you should *always* call `Dispose()` when you're finished with the object. The `using` block in C# and VB.NET are language-specific mechanisms for ensuring that `Dispose` gets called. This is true for all objects that implement `IDisposable`, so it's probably a good idea to look at other areas of your code and other framework objects that you're using to ensure that you're following this pattern. Some things you might want to pay particular attention to are:

- Database connections
- Anything IO related (files, streams of any kind, etc.)

Second, for this particular case, the `TextWriter` class buffers the data that gets written (so, for example, if you write the data a character at a time, you don't have disk IO for EVERY character, since it does it in "chunks"). As a result, the buffer has to be flushed in order for data to get written to the disk. This happens under three cases:

- The buffer fills up under the course of using the object in code
- You close the `TextWriter` either by calling `Close()` or `Dispose()`
- You manually flush the buffer by calling `Flush()`

The first one you have no control over, as it's automatic. The latter should be an exceptional case, where you want all buffered data written to disk immediately but still want to keep the writer open. The second case--the most important--is what you're missing.

Comment: I must apologize, I have in fact had tw.Close(); at the end of the consoles main function. Still not working as I expect. Perhaps the buffer isn't big enough for all the data?

Comment: I have been very stupid. I had found a console.readline above tw.close. This meant that I was not closing the textwriter. Thanks adam for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Michael: The buffer size just determines how much data sits in memory before it gets to disk; the buffer doesn't determine how *much* data can be written, just how often it actually happens. Just so I'm clear, a) you've verified that the contents of `mList` is correct (how did you verify this?) b) The console shows incorrect data (incorrect how? missing entries? additional entries?), and c) the file shows incorrect data that's *different* from what shows up in the console?

Comment: @Michael: Aha! That makes more sense. Glad to help.